# How do I modify the <li> <a> <a/> </li> with wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, menus, html

I try to add an "alt=" attribute to the `<a>` of the menu in WordPress but I don't see the form, look in the whole template and I can't find information other than `wp_nav_menu()`

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'container'      => false,
            'fallback_cb'    => 'orbital_default_menu',
            'items_wrap'     => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        )
    );
?>
```

What I can hardly understand is that the `<ul>%3$s</ul>` variable generates `<li> <a> </a> </li>`

Any way to modify the `<a> </a>` using `wp_nav_menu()`?

Comment: I believe `alt` is for images, not for `<a>`.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to WPSO. You need to modify the Walker_Nav_Menu Class. That class is responsible for rendering the HTML menu output in first place. The theme you are using is calling the WordPress menu class, which will then output your menu.

As alexwc_ mentioned the alt attribute is for images, not for anchor tags.

So in order to maniputelate the menu output, you need to implement your own "walker".

See:

[Custom Nav Walker Tutorial](https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/)

[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArEmwJV6M7s&t=10s)

Comment: Using a link to *'whatever'* in an answer isn't a very good idea. What if they *'die'*, then the question stays partly open/unanswered and ppl have to do a search for another answer when there is one at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, I think this type of question could have easily been answered in first place by simply googleing and reading maybe half an hour. So my answer was pointing in the right direction. It's not my task to cover his  topic with code line by line. The way should be clear - modify/write a Navwalker.